# excuting a shel command in a spring batch listener

Tags: spring-batch, java-7

I am using spring batch with Java 7 to do some stuff.
When my batch finish to generate the result file i want to execute  some linux command line ( coping it into a CFT server).
I added the following line of code for the listner:

@Bean
public JobExecutionListener envoieCFT() {

```
    JobExecutionListener listener = new JobExecutionListener() {
        @Override
        public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {}

        @Override
        public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
            
            final String command ="scp <file path> <user>@<ip@>:< where to copy the file>";
            boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name")
                      .toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
            Process process;
            if (!isWindows) {
                try {
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                      .exec(String.format(command));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Job finished notification");
        }
    };

    return listener ;
}
```

it's not working at all, did someonde ever faced the same probleme?